# Quick function/operator for getting the magnitude |x| of a variable

Tags: perl

Is there an operator in perl, or even a function in some module, that will get the magnitude of a number similar to what is denoted by the mathematical notation |x|.

e.g.

```
x = 42, y = -42
|x| = |y| = 42
```

If there isn't one, what is the simplest way of extracting such a magnitude? I can think of two that I have used before:

```
$x = -42;

# quick regex for whole integers, can be extended to take decimals into account
$y = $x =~ /(\d+)/; 

# Using if statements
$y = $x*-1 if $x < 0;
```

I would have to create a new function to use either of these examples if I wanted to get the magnitude without adding extra lines to my code (I need to retrieve these magnitudes quite often). I am concerned that I might have missed something even easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's the [`abs`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/abs.html) function for that.

```
 $ perl -e 'print abs(-42), "\n";'
42
```

Comment: OMG, my search skills have failed me again. In retrospect, the word "magnitude" does not appear to be used often for this type of operation. Thanks!